# Daylightsavings return 1 if select statment is empty, otherwise return 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I am working on a daylight offset function and would like to hear your oppinion on how to solve this problem. Suppose I create a Stored Procedure which contains following code (input is the current time `@time`):

```
SELECT*
from
dbo.DaylightSavings
WHERE @time between Timestart AND Timeend
```

Now if the `SELECT` statement above returns a table view, then the dayligt savings should be ON and therefore the stored procedure should return an offset of +2. Otherwise, if the `SELECT` statement above **does not** return a table view then the daylightsavings should be OFF and the stored procedure would return +1 instead. How would I make a reasonable Stored Procedure which handles this logic?

thanks!

System:

MS SQL 2008R2

Comment: If I understood you correctly, I would do an `SELECT COUNT(*)` instead and store the result in a variable. Afterwards you can distinguish what to return depending on the variable value being 0 or greater than 0.

Comment: What is @time? The UTC time? The local time?  In what time zone?  You realize daylight saving time is *different* in different time zones?  How do you handle overlap during fall-back or gap during spring-forward?  In general, it's not a great idea to perform this function in SQL.  It's a better fit for application-level code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want (assuming the 'offset' is hours):

```
DECLARE @Count INT
SET @Count = (  SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM
                dbo.DaylightSavings
                WHERE @time between Timestart AND Timeend)

IF @Count > 0   
    SELECT DATEADD(HH, 2, @time)
ELSE IF @Count = 0
    SELECT DATEADD(HH, 1, @time)
```